# How to stop OSSEC HIDS sending me level 2 alerts?

Tags: configuration, customization, ossec

I have [OSSEC HIDS](https://ossec.github.io/downloads.html) (2.8.3) installed (I have it set up as a `local` installation) and setup so that it sends me email alerts for the various alert levels. The only problem is with level 2 alerts which are normally nothing of importance and just spam my inbox.

So I was wondering if there is any way of stopping it from sending me level 2 alerts so that it sends me all the others but just not those? (I am looking for something which I can configure in the OSSEC HIDS settings, I don't want a sort of just external hack which filters the emails it sends me or something because that could run the risk of it filtering out other alert levels too.)

Answer (score 2):

For say if you want to get only alerts greater than 8 you can filter that by adding the below snippet in your server's ossec.conf file,

```
-email_alerts-
-level-8-/level-
-/email_alerts-
```

**Not sure why couldn't use <>** symbols use <> instead of - for opening and closing brackets
This will help to trigger alerts levels of 8 and 8+.